# Return opposite transaction value rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table structure and I want a query that needs to be returning opposite side columns values.

```
CREATE TABLE TransactionDetail
(
  ID NUMERIC NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  TransactionCode bigint,
  COATitle NVARCHAR(50),
  DrAmount NUMERIC,
  CrAmount NUMERIC
);

INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (1, 1, 'Overtime', '2500', NULL);
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (2, 1, 'Internship', NULL, '1500');
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (3, 1, 'Medical', NULL, '1000');
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (4, 2, 'Internship', '1150', NULL);
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (5, 2, 'Overtime', NULL, '1150');
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (6, 3, 'Overtime', '600', NULL);
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (7, 3, 'Refreshment', '400', NULL);
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (8, 3, 'Car Loan', '200', NULL);
INSERT INTO TransactionDetail VALUES (9, 3, 'Office Expenses', NULL, '1200');
```

If I pass parameter with value `Overtime` then it should return following rows

```
SELECT COATitle, DrAmount, CrAmount
FROM TransactionDetail
WHERE COATitle <> Overtime

Internship      NULL    1500
Medical         NULL    1000
Internship      1150    NULL
Office Expenses NULL    1200
```

The logic is against each transaction if the selected Account is on `Debit` side it should print the `Credit` side accounts and if the selected Account is on `Credit` side it should print `Debit` side accounts against that specific `TransactionCode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code gives the desired result. It does that by checking to see whether the provided parameter is a debit or credit (or doesn't exist) in the current transaction, then only displays the reverse as specified.

```
declare @Parameter nvarchar(50) = 'Overtime'

declare @Trans TABLE
(
  ID NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  TransactionCode bigint,
  COATitle NVARCHAR(50),
  DrAmount NUMERIC,
  CrAmount NUMERIC
);

INSERT INTO @Trans VALUES (1, 1, 'Overtime', '2500', NULL);
INSERT INTO @Trans VALUES (2, 1, 'Internship', NULL, '1500');
INSERT INTO @Trans VALUES (3, 1, 'Medical', NULL, '1000');
INSERT INTO @Trans VALUES (4, 2, 'Internship', '1150', NULL);
INSERT INTO @Trans VALUES (5, 2, 'Overtime', NULL, '1150');
INSERT INTO @Trans VALUES (6, 3, 'Overtime', '600', NULL);
INSERT INTO @Trans VALUES (7, 3, 'Refreshment', '400', NULL);
INSERT INTO @Trans VALUES (8, 3, 'Car Loan', '200', NULL);
INSERT INTO @Trans VALUES (9, 3, 'Office Expenses', NULL, '1200');

select TransactionCode, COATitle, DrAmount, CrAmount
from (
  SELECT TransactionCode, COATitle, DrAmount, CrAmount
    , case when exists (select 1 from @Trans T1 where T1.TransactionCode = T.TransactionCode and T1.COATitle = @Parameter and DrAmount is not null) then 1
      when exists (select 1 from @Trans T1 where T1.TransactionCode = T.TransactionCode and T1.COATitle = @Parameter and CrAmount is not null) then -1
      else 0 end TransSign
  FROM @Trans T
  WHERE COATitle <> @Parameter
) X
where (TransSign = -1 and DrAmount is not null)
or (TransSign = 1 and CrAmount is not null)
```